# MKMapRectContainsRect returns false even if I've set an overlay?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I'm a little new to Objective C and iOS programming, I've been exploring MKMapView recently, and I've been able to add annotations successfully.

`[self.mapView addAnnotations:annotations]`

However,

when I try to add an overlay, I'm running into issues,

I add the overlay and then I need to add `setVisibileMapRect`.

When I write something like this-

```
    [self.mapView addOverlay:MyOverlayObject]

    BOOL mapContainsOverlay = MKMapRectContainsRect(self.mapView.visibleMapRect,
                                 [MyOverlayObject boundingMapRect]);

    if (mapContainsOverlay) {
            //This is not getting executed.
      }

     NSLog(@" %hhd", mapContainsOverlay) //Prints 0
```

Any Idea why `mapContainsOverlay` is 0?

Comment: What kind of overlay is MyOverlayObject?  NSLog the values of the two rects you are comparing.

Comment: @Anna I'm using https://github.com/ryanolsonk/HeatMapDemo/ for the OverlayObject. They aren't same when I NSLog them. They're very different.  What I don't understand is why are they different?

Comment: The visibleMapRect is the area currently shown in the map view which can be different from the boundingMapRect of an overlay which define the overlay's extents.  Question is whether that overlay's extents fit completely inside the currently-viewed area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the map is looking at England, and the overlay is in New Zealand then `self.mapView.visibleMapRect` does not contain `[MyOverlayObject boundingMapRect]` and thus `MKMapRectContainsRect` returns false (which is printed as 0). I don't know what your rects are but I'm guessing that the rect2 doesn't fit "entirely within rect1" [as per the spec](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitFunctionsReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/MKMapRectContainsRect). e.g. France does not contain Europe.

If you want to ensure that your map is looking at where the overlay you need to [set the visible map rect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/setVisibleMapRect%3aanimated%3a).

Comment: When I set visible map rect, It goes into some kind of an infinite loop.

Comment: That sounds like another question, and in that question you should share the code that sets the maprect and the code that reacts to it.